# How to Sum particular values in a column in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sum

I'm kinda new to this and I have been stuck on this for a while now.

Example:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
 A  | H  | 1
 A  | I  | 2
 A  | J  | 3
 B  | J  | 4 
 B  | K  | 5
 C  | L  | 6
```

How can I sum 'Col3' but only for particular values. For example sum up the values in 'Col3' where the letters in 'Col1' are in the same row as 'Col3'. So A = 6 (1+2+3) and B = 9 (4+5) and C = 6

So you get this:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
 A  | H  | 6   
 A  | I  | 6
 A  | J  | 6
 B  | J  | 9 
 B  | K  | 9
 C  | L  | 6
```

This is what I had so far:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, SUM(Col3)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Col1, Col2;
```

Thanks

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: How about    sum(Col3) over (partition by Col1)

Answer (score 4):

Just to elaborate on my comment.

You can use the window function `sum() over()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Col1] varchar(50),[Col2] varchar(50),[Col3] int)  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('A','H',1)
,('A','I',2)
,('A','J',3)
,('B','J',4)
,('B','K',5)
,('C','L',6)

Select Col1
      ,Col2
      ,Col3 = sum(Col3) over (partition by Col1)
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
A       H       6
A       I       6
A       J       6
B       J       9
B       K       9
C       L       6
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as another way you can do this way also using `join` and [SUM (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
 function.

```
create table TestTable (Col1 varchar(5)
     , Col2 varchar(5)
     , Col3 int)

insert into TestTable Values
 ('A', 'H', 1),
 ('A', 'I', 2),
 ('A', 'J', 3),
 ('B', 'J', 4),
 ('B', 'K', 5),
 ('C', 'L', 6)

SELECT tblA.Col1
    ,tblA.Col2
    ,tblB.Col3
FROM (
    SELECT Col1
        ,Col2
    FROM TestTable
    ) tblA
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Col1
        ,sum(Col3) AS Col3
    FROM TestTable
    GROUP BY Col1
    ) tblB ON tblA.Col1 = tblB.Col1
```

[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=07e8118389b1359ae1625669bbc02026)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to write data aggregation queries like this. Which to use depends on what your final results need to look like. Just to go over some basics, I’ll go over several methods here.

The simplest is to use a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT Col1, sum(Col3)
 from MyTable
 where Col1 = 'A'
```

This will produce a single row of data:

```
Col1 Col3
 A  | 6
```

To produce sums for all of the distinct values in ColA, you would use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Col1, sum(Col3)
 from MyTable
 group by Col1
```

This will produce three rows of data:

```
Col1 Col3
 A  | 6   
 B  | 9
 C  | 6
```

The above samples are pretty straightforward and basic SQL examples. It is actually a bit difficult to produce the result set from your example, where you include Col2 and show the summation, because Col2 is not part of the data aggregation. Several ways to do this:

Using a subquery:

```
SELECT
   mt.Col1
  ,mt.Col2
  ,sub.SumCol3  Col3
 from MyTable  mt
  inner join (select
                 Col1
                ,sum(Col3)  SumCol3
               from MyTable
               group by Col1)  sub
   on sub.Col1 = mt.Col1
```

Using a common table expression:

```
WITH cteSub
 as (select
        Col1
       ,sum(Col3)  SumCol3
      from MyTable
      group by Col1)
select
   mt.Col1
  ,mt.Col2
  ,cteSub.SumCol3  Col3
 from MyTable  mt
  inner join cteSub
   on ctesub.Col1 = mt.Col1
```

And, perhaps the most obscure and obtuse, using aggregation fucntions with partitioning:

```
SELECT
   Col1
  ,Col2
  ,sum(Col3) over (partition by Col1)  Col3
from MyTable
```

Thorough and complete discussions of all the above tactics (better than anything I'd write) can be found online, by searching for "SQL" plus the appropriate term (aggregation, subquery, CTE, paritioning functions). Good luck!